# Calling Coffeescript variables in Slim

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, slim-lang

Im trying to declare a coffescript function and call it later in the code. I'm pretty new to this, and can't seem to find anything on it.

Here is the code im working on, as you can see I try to call the square function:

```
coffee:
  @square = (x) -> x * x

p square(3)
```

Here i want to get a p-tag containing "9"

Comment: it is not possible to execute coffescript in .erb files. If you want a view helper, just make a rails helper

Comment: How would you print a javascript variable in erb / slim in the first place?

Comment: it's not a .erb file, its a .html.slim file

Comment: that makes no difference if it is a .erb, or .haml or .slim template. The rails template parser cannot execute coffeescript, it can only convert coffeescript to javascript, and output it in the html

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've obviously been attacking this the wrong way. Thank you for answering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like so

```
p
 coffee:
   document.write @square(3)
```

But !!NEVER EVER!! write such horrible things.
In ROR Slim templates are for ruby only. And please don't define any methods there.